# Запуск команд одна за другой в функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я не могу понять, как запустить следующую строчку кода в функции, только после того, как предыдущие были выполнены.

```
def processscan(scanfile):
    cache_delete(Cache_path)
    time.sleep(2)
    copy_files(pro)
    time.sleep(2)
    subprocess.Popen([
    'C:\\Program Files\\LM\\LM.exe',
    '-addFolder',
    TEMP_FOLDER_LM,
    '-import',
    folder1,
    '-update',
    '-session',
    '-save',
    save_project,
    '-quit'
    ])
    time.sleep(2)
    cache_delete(Cache_path)
    time.sleep(2)
    cache_delete(TEMP_FOLDER)
    time.sleep(2)
    copy_files(nor)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Программа запускает некоторые действия (копирование и удаление) с файлами, потом открывает программу и делает в ней действия с этими файлами. Но тут же, не дожидаясь конца, вызывается следующая функция копирования и удаления файлов. Выскакивают ошибки, что нет доступа к файлу, потому что он используется другим приложением. Как я могу сделать так, чтобы `cache_delete(Cache_path)` и `cache_delete(TEMP_FOLDER)` вызывались только тогда, когда `subprocess.Popen` выполнил все действия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никто не читает [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)

```
process = subprocess.Popen(...)
process.wait()
```